# internet explorer security message appintegrator mindspark

Tags: internet-explorer

Hi every time i open internet explorer i am getting warning message  from  ie security saying appintegrator.exe wants to make changes to your computer 
this message springs so frequently it is almost impossible to go anywhere

Comment: i have uninstalled it (..galaxy) and was able to delete a folder with same name but there is another folder was unable to delete it says being used by another program... however when i opened IE  is working fine

Comment: but right now  ie security is giving the same security messages for java se and adobe ..in the same annoying way